# Unbiased estimation for variable X with $f(x)=x^\alpha$

Tags: probability

> A random variable X has density function $F(x)=x^\alpha (0<x<1,a>-1)$. Find LME. Is the estimation unbaised? b. Is the estimation $\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}$ is unbiased ?

About the first, I found maximum for the function, which is got is $\frac{-n}{\sum ln(X_i)}$. Now when I need to calculate expected value I'm stuck with $\int\limits_0^1\frac{x}{\sum ln(X_i)}dx$ which I don't know how to calculate. The same situation with the second one, except that the problematic integral here is $\int\limits_0^1\frac{x\sum X_i}{n-\sum X_i}dx$. How can I simplify the integrals? Maybe I don't really need to calculate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding you properly, but is it at all possible that you meant the random variable has a **distribution** function $F(x) = x^a; 0\leq x \leq 1; a>-1$ and not **density**? The distribution must equal 0 at the low end and 1 at the upper end. The integral of the density must be 1. In other words, for any density $f(x)$, we need:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx = 1
$$
In your case:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^a\;dx = \frac{1}{a+1}
$$
so it is not a proper density and would need a scale factor of $a+1$.

I'm not familiar with what you mean by "LME". Are you looking for the value of the mean given $a$? Are you looking for the maximum likelihood estimate of $a$ given data?

Under the assumption that $x^a$ is the distribution and not the density, we would have the density $f(x) = ax^{a-1}$ which does integrate to 1 under the limits provided.

Given $a$, the mean then becomes:
$$
E(X) = \int_{0}^{1} xax^{a-1}\;dx = \int_{0}^{1} ax^a\;dx = \frac{a}{a+1}
$$

Given data, the likelihood of each value $x$ is $ax^{a-1}$. The likelihood of *all* the data is the product of the likelihoods of the observations which is:
$$
a^n\prod_i{x_i^{a-1}}
$$
The loglikelihood would be:
$$
n\ln{a}+(a-1)\sum_i{\ln{x_i}}
$$
Taking the first derivative and setting equal to 0 gives:
$$
\frac{n}{a} + \sum_i{\ln{x_i}} = 0
$$
So
$$
a = -\frac{n}{\sum_i{\ln{x_i}}}
$$
Hope that helps.